# Multiple values in column MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How my system works is that a user may be assigned to several things.

A column is called `group` and they may be assigned to several groups, e.g `1`,`5`,`8` etc... Is there a way to store them in the **same** column?

Comment: Please add proper table schema with sample data along with desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** store relations in single column. [Normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data and introduce new table which will hold references for user group relations like

Table user_groups

```
user_id group_id

1       1
1       5
1       8
```

Also have a look at [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)